# image picker controller custom backgrounds

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have currently implemented a UIImagePickerController for sending images in my messaging app. Now I am wanting to use the same sort of logic, but to set custom backgrounds...

I am using `PresentPhotoLibrary(self, YES);`to get to my picker

```
#pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    NSURL *video = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    UIImage *picture = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [self messageSend:nil Video:video Picture:picture Audio:nil];
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

which I use to send picture messages... do I need to use this same image picker to set backgrounds? Or do I need to have two separate image Picker controllers to do this?

Comment: you can use the same picker, you need to change the data that is passed to this picker.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I don't agree. There's no reason to reuse a UIImagePickerController, and it causes problems when you do.

Comment: What difference do you imagine it makes? Did you try it and it failed? What happened? What's the problem?

Comment: what kind of problems @matt ?

Comment: How do I make my presentPhotoLibrary show a different image picker though?

Comment: "show a different image picker: What is a "different image picker"? An image picker is an image picker. It's a dialog.

Comment: I was thinking of the normal picker with images....I didn't think of the picker controller. @matt

Comment: I guess this is a better question. Currently when I call to change the background and click choose with this image picture, it sends an image. How would I modify this to know the context of how it was called? This is my first experience with imagepickers

Comment: Give it a different delegate.

Comment: so like - (void)imagePickerController2:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

Answer (score 2):

The question turns out to be: Given that I'm going to present UIImagePickerController for more than one purpose, how can I distinguish *which* purpose *this* UIImagePickerController was presented for?

The simplest approach is to have different delegates for the different purposes. When you present UIImagePickerController, you set a different `delegate` object. That object knows how to respond to one of the *particular* purposes for which you are using UIPickerController.

Another possibility would be to use the same `delegate` but, in that object, to throw a switch of some sort. For example, you could have a Bool property. Set it to `true` for one purpose and `false` for the other purpose. Then present the picker. The delegate code consults the same Bool property and now knows what to do.

Comment: So how would I go about doing that? I understand what you are saying, making the function polymorphic and what not, just not the implementation.

Comment: I'm not going to write the code for you, if that's what you're asking. I've said what I'm going to say. In my opinion I've answered the question pretty throughly.

Comment: I'm asking about what you mean by the delegate. Are you talking about passing another parameter to my function so when its true do one thing and when its false, do another?

Comment: and also, I do not understand how my code gets from  PresentPhotoLibrary(YES, Self) to the imagepicker...

Comment: "I'm asking about what you mean by the delegate" I mean the [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/delegate).